# i need a good layout for my forms

Tags: css

I need some great idea in designing form contain some fieldsets.
Where can i find a nice collection? Is there anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, read for example [**this article on Sitepoint**](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/fancy-form-design-css) or look at image replacing techniques or CSS3 solutions

Answer (score 2):

To start off with I would recommend reading this article by Cameron Adams. It takes you through the markup side of things and shows you how to set it up in a nice css friendly way:

- http://articles.sitepoint.com/print/fancy-form-design-css

There is a nice gallery (with 77 examples at the time of posting) which will show you a lot of design inspirations for laying it out once you have the markup sorted:

- http://www.smileycat.com/design_elements/registration_forms/

Comment: haha its a good link! I didnt steal it off you though lol - http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=+site%3Aforums.asp.net+%2Brtpharry+%2Bsitepoint+%2Bform

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of Smashing Magazine, and here's a good article/collection of [what you're looking for](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2006/11/11/css-based-forms-modern-solutions/).

Several good templates [here](http://toolkit.crispen.org/index.php?cat=templates) and [here](http://www.noupe.com/css/47-excellent-ajax-css-forms.html) as well.